# Gradle Duplicate Entry: java.util.zip.ZipException com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

Tags: android

I am working on an android app. every time i try to run this app I get this error.

**"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class.**"

I have tried all solutions in this and other forums but nothing works.

this is my build.gradle(module:app). thanks in advance.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "etc.solved.problem.gideon.androidalertapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'play-services-tasks-10.0.1'
}}

    ependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you applying the gms.google-services plugin twice or is that a typo?  Because if you are, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2 and the new SDK, com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1. You cannot use them together in the same app.

check out  firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)